# How to trigger document level events from a jasmine test Angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, jasmine2.0

According to the Angular Testing documentation, to trigger the events from the tests, we use the `triggerEventHandler()` method on the debug element. This method takes the `event name` and the `object`. Now, this works if we are adding the events using the `HostListener`. For ex: `@HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])` or to add a `document` level event, we do it something like this `@HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])`.

In my current directive implementation, as I cannot nest the HostListeners, I add the `document` level events using the `document.addEventListener` inside a `HostListener`.
 
Code is as follows:

```
@HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
callMouseDown(event){
  if (something) {
   document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.callMouseMove.bind(this));
  }
}

callMouseMove(event){
 // do some computations.
}
```

Now, I want to trigger the `mousemove` event which is added at the `document` level from my tests. The current implementation of `triggerEventHandler()` doesn't work, i.e., the listener is not fired in the test.

How can I get this to work? Could anyone help me with some guidance.

Edit: Added Test:

```
it('test spec', inject([MyService], (service: MyService) =>{
   x = [];
  //service calls the method
  service.evtEmit.subscribe(e => {
   x.push(e);
  });
  triggerEventHandler("mousedown", {pageX: 200, pageY: 300});
  triggerEventHandler("document:mousemove", {pageX: 250, pageY: 320});
  // the above statement won't work.
  expect(arr).toEqual({x:50, y: 20});
}));
```

Comment: Is this `this.callMouseMove()` correct syntax?

Comment: Can you also add your test?

Comment: @yurzui Hi, I updated the test. and I made a mistake in the syntax of calling the function which I fixed it now.

Comment: `document.dispatchEvent(new Event("mousemove"))` will trigger event

Comment: @yurzui how do I pass the object here?

Comment: `const event  = new Event("mousemove"); event.pageX = 250; document.dispatchEvent(event)`

Comment: @yurzui I think your way of doing is the right way because my way doesn't work if I have a private method inside the directive. +1 for your answer. Maybe the user who posted would change their mind if you post it as an answer :)

Comment: @yurzui But I am very curious, if one can do this in more elegant way like in one single line? Using CustomEvent?

Comment: @ShellZero hey, yes you can use CustomEvent as alternative. And yes, I think my way is the right way for testing such things

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like the similar problem which you have described is logged as the issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12518) on angular repo.

You can get the access of the directive with the component instance and can access the method (i.e., in your case it's the callMouseMove).
The following way should work:

```
it('test spec', inject([MyService], (service: MyService) => {
   x = [];
  //service calls the method
  service.evtEmit.subscribe(e => {
   x.push(e);
  });
  triggerEventHandler("mousedown", {pageX: 200, pageY: 300});
  component.directive.callMouseMove({pageX: 250, pageY: 320});
  expect(arr).toEqual({x:50, y: 20});
}));
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

I realized that my way doesn't work if you have private methods inside your directive. It is better to create custom events or in this case a mouse event programmatically and trigger the events either at document level or on the element itself. This method was mentioned by [yurzui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui). Thanks to him.

Here's how you can do it:

```
function programmaticTrigger(eventType: string, evtObj: any) {
   let evt = new MouseEvent(eventType, evtObj);
   document.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

You can call this function from your spec as:

```
programmaticTrigger("mousemove", {clientX: 250, clientY: 320});
```

Note that, I am not passing `pageX` or `pageY` here in this case, because they are `readonly` but they are computed internally based on the `clientX` and `clientY` values.

If you want to create a custom event and pass in whatever values you want, you can do as follows:

```
function programmaticTrigger(eventType: string, evtObj: any) {
       let evt: any;
       evt = Event(eventType, evtObj);
       document.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
```

Invoke it as follows:

```
programmaticTrigger("mousemove", {pageX: 250, pageY: 320});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution to this problem. See below if you want to know why [ShellZero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4873295/shellzero)'s answer doesn't work for me.

My solution is to create an injectable "wrapper" service that can return `document`. That way, in production it gets the document as usual, but in tests, I can mock the wrapper and supply my own "document" and dispatch events to it.

**document-wrapper.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DocumentWrapperService {

  constructor() { }

  public getDocument() {
    return document;
  }
}
```

In my component, I can inject this service in the constructor and get `document` from it. In my case, I use it in the `ngOnInit` method.

**some.component.ts**

```
import { DocumentWrapperService } from './../../../services/document-wrapper/document-wrapper.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: '<div id="container"><!-- Your HTML here --></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.css']
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private documentWrapper: DocumentWrapperService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const _document = this.documentWrapper.getDocument();

    _document.addEventListener('mouseup', ($event: MouseEvent) => {
      // do something on mouse-up
    });

}
```

This requires a little bit of extra work in the test. I have to make a mock wrapper and inject it. By default, my mock returns `document` so existing tests don't break.

```
import { DocumentWrapperService } from './../../../services/document-wrapper/document-wrapper.service';
import * as td from 'testdouble';

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    // I use testdouble to make my mock, but you could roll your own or use some other library.
    mockDocumentWrapper = td.object(DocumentWrapperService.prototype);
    td.when(mockDocumentWrapper.getDocument()).thenReturn(document);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SomeComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: DocumentWrapperService, useValue: mockDocumentWrapper }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Then, in my spec method where I'm testing the event handling, I have to set up my mock to return a different element instead of `document`. The best thing I've found is to use the outermost `div` of the component itself. Because my call to `addEventListener` is in `ngOnInit`, I also have to call `ngOnInit` again. Once I've done that, I'm free to dispatch the event and make my expectations.

```
it("should do something when the user releases the mouse button", () => {
  const rootDivElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector("#container");
  td.when(mockDocumentWrapper.getDocument()).thenReturn(rootDivElement);
  component.ngOnInit();

  rootDivElement.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup', { clientY: 100, clientX: 200 }));

  // expectations go here
});
```

While [ShellZero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4873295/shellzero)'s answer is the best I could find, it wasn't satisfying to me. When testing an event handler on an Angular component, I don't think it's adequate to call the handler method on the component itself, because it doesn't prove that the component has subscribed to the correct event. I prefer to trigger the event and expect the component to react correctly.

The "Update" section in [ShellZero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4873295/shellzero)'s answer straight-up didn't work when I implemented it. I think it's because Karma puts the Angular components in an iFrame, which has no access to the root document. If that's wrong, I'd love to know.

The one thing I don't like about my solution is that it adds production code that is only required to make testing possible. I would normally prefer to jump through lots of hoops in my tests to avoid changing the production code for the sake of testing. In this case, I could not see a way to do that.